# inner product question <,>

Tags: inner-products

Pleace help, that is true or false

> Let, $a$, $u$ and $v$ $\in \mathbb{R} $, with $v \neq 0 $, $<,>$ is inner product
>   \begin{eqnarray*}
> <u,v >&=&<a,v>\\
> <u,v>-<a,v>&=&0\\
> <u-a,v>&=0&
> \end{eqnarray*} 
>   Then, $u=a$ ???

Thanks

Comment: Is this supposed to be true for every $v$, or a particular $v$?

Comment: @Daryl $v$ is fixed but arbitrary.

Comment: In that case, I don't think that you can conclude that $u=a$. If $\langle u-a,v\rangle=0$ for all $v$, then this would require $u-a=0$. If $v$ is fixed, then $\langle u-a,v\rangle=0$ gives that $u-a$ and $v$ are orthogonal. In this case, you can't conclude that $u-a=0$. Note that I have assumed $a$ is also fixed, but $u$ can be chosen.

Comment: If $\langle\ , \rangle$ is the inner product on $\mathbb{R}$ then $\langle u, v\rangle  = uv$. Is the inner product supposed to be on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Daryl  ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As Daryl has pointed out, it is sufficient that $u-a$ is orthogonal to $v$. In this case the dot product $<u-a,v>$ will be $0$, even if $u-a$ is non zero ($u \ne a)$. 
An example in 2-dimensional euclidean space is $u=(1, 2)$, $a=(5,8)$, $v=(9,-6)$. In this case, $<u,v>=<a,v>=-3$ but $u \ne a$.